# Cannot use more than two custom tags in a custom div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have this code:-

```js
const h1= (tag) => {
    const ptag = document.querySelector(tag);
          const shadow = ptag.attachShadow({
              mode: 'open'
            });
          const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
          h1.innerHTML = ptag.innerHTML;
          shadow.appendChild(h1);
      }
  const h2= (tag) => {
    const ptag = document.querySelector(tag);
          const shadow = ptag.attachShadow({
              mode: 'open'
            });
          const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
          h2.innerHTML = ptag.innerHTML;
          shadow.appendChild(h2);
      }
      const div = (tag) => {
  const ptag = document.querySelector(tag);
        const shadow = ptag.attachShadow({
            mode: 'closed'
          });
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = ptag.innerHTML;
        shadow.appendChild(div);
    }
h1('city-name');
h2('we-data');
h2('temp-data');
div('weather-app');
```

```html
<weather-app>
<city-name>London</city-name>
<we-data>Rains</we-data>
<temp-data>15 C</temp-data>
<city-name>Hi. Does thhis look like h1 text?</city-name>
</weather-app>
```

I expected everything to work fine, with 'London' been shown big and bold like h1, and the other two in h2. But I could not understand what went wrong and now they show up as normal text. If I use only two elements in weather-app, they work fine, but more than two, dosen't work. And another one, if you use a defined element twice, like I used we-data twice, the first will show up as defined but the second one will show up like normal text. Please try a fix on this.
Answers and comments appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is kinda what you want. The problem seems to be the `shadow.appendChild()` I think you need to use `shadow.host`

```
const h1 = (tag) => {
  const ptag = document.querySelector(tag);
  const shadow = ptag.attachShadow({
    mode: 'open'
  });
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.innerHTML = ptag.innerHTML;
  shadow.host.parentNode.replaceChild(h1,shadow.host);
}
```

Also, don't use `.appendChild()` but use `.replaceChild()`

**Demo**

```js
const h1 = (tag) => {
  const ptag = document.querySelector(tag);
  const shadow = ptag.attachShadow({
    mode: 'open'
  });
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.innerHTML = ptag.innerHTML;
  h1.style.color = "blue";
  shadow.host.parentNode.replaceChild(h1,shadow.host);
}
const h2 = (tag) => {
  const ptag = document.querySelector(tag);
  const shadow = ptag.attachShadow({
    mode: 'open'
  });
  const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
  h2.innerHTML = ptag.innerHTML;
  shadow.host.parentNode.replaceChild(h2,shadow.host);
}
const div = (tag) => {
  const ptag = document.querySelector(tag);
  const shadow = ptag.attachShadow({
    mode: 'closed'
  });
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = ptag.innerHTML;
  shadow.host.parentNode.replaceChild(div,shadow.host);
}
h1('city-name');
h2('we-data');
h2('temp-data');
h1('city-name');
div('weather-app');
```

```html
<weather-app>
  <city-name>London</city-name>
  <we-data>Rains</we-data>
  <temp-data>15 C</temp-data>
  <city-name>Hi. Does thhis look like h1 text?</city-name>
</weather-app>
```

Comment: Can you help me with the thin g that the second text 'Hi. Does thhis look like h1 text?' does not look like the london one?

Comment: Since you have some sort of loop in your code ten you can just add `h1('city-name');` again

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. You are 'God in disguise'

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd No problem, happy to help.

Comment: Not able to add styles, please help @Carsten Løvbo Andersen

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd lets say you want the h1 text to be blue, you do `h1.style.color = "blue";`

Comment: I'd like to inherit it from the parent element

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd what style from the parent element are you talking about, you have to be a bit more specific.

Comment: i meant that since weather-module will be replaced by div, so div should retain all properties of weather-module like style,etc

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd well I can't see what styles your weather-app has, so it's hard to give you an good answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200291/discussion-between-obnoxiousnerd-and-carsten-lovbo-andersen).

Comment: Made a method, and it works:- ``` const extendCSS = (el1, el2) =>{
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector(el1).attributes).forEach(function(item) {
    el2.setAttribute(item.name, item.value);
  });
} ``` It takes attributes to first div and inherits to second div.

Answer (score 1):

1. As stated in another answer by @Carsten Løvbo Andersen - use `shadow.host` and `replaceChild()`
2. [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns first matched element, [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns all matched elements, so you need `.querySelectorAll()`
3. Your `h1`, `h2` and `div` functions all look awfully similar - I took a liberty and rewritten them

```js
const foo = (elementTag, shadowMode) => tag => {
  const query = document.querySelectorAll(tag);
  query.forEach(ptag => {
    const shadow = ptag.attachShadow({
      mode: shadowMode
    });
    const element = document.createElement(elementTag);
    element.innerHTML = ptag.innerHTML;
    shadow.host.parentNode.replaceChild(element, shadow.host);
  });
};

const h1 = foo('h1', 'open');
const h2 = foo('h2', 'open');
const div = foo('div', 'closed');

h1('city-name');
h2('we-data');
h2('temp-data');
div('weather-app');
```

```html
<weather-app>
  <city-name>London</city-name>
  <we-data>Rains</we-data>
  <temp-data>15 C</temp-data>
  <city-name>Hi. Does thhis look like h1 text?</city-name>
</weather-app>
```

Comment: so querySelectorAll will select all elems of the required type, am I right

Comment: Something like that. I linked MDN article in my answer, you can get more info there.

Comment: i got another problem:- Cannot set css of those elements, please help, @fen1x